# facebook login is'nt redirect back properly

Tags: laravel, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-php-sdk

Working with Laravel 5.2
Using SammyK/LaravelFacebookSdk

I have an web application witch users can vote in each category once so before they can vote they have to login to facebook everything working fine until it comes to the redirect the user to the page with message like thanks for voting here is the application on the internet [Here](http://satfestival.net/vote/1)

Now whenever the user click on vote I get different responses on my PC on

- chrome everything working OK
- on Firefox and other devices Not working
  Whet happens is is the voting done successfully but the redirect back not

it go to this URL

```
https://www.facebook.com/v2.9/dialog/oauth?client_id=139382809958016&state=d517376c10784f6b5f718112a7c49b83&response_type=code&sdk=php-sdk-5.5.0&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fsatfestival.net%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&scope=email%2Cuser_events#_=_
```

and redirect back to this URL

```
satfestival.net/facebook/callback/?code=AQApHGQa5LtqLSv75bq8V6QA_6I9ivmKJ07kcO3aYY7pCmSIYoPu8lzrZhRSGYXg7weiOgIa5c1vKDchsbVepn0-LH9rh1kUKgpcJ71DFtYqbZLMLfEYD1DJWmqyqoFS_RL03b2IhZx62LP8NyepCZ0zTn8auxzGN2-jhtZ-YHVFPuGlJI31UnCc7ymhCXu1Zie8hMxp38z5CvPrhE5lDEEQjDgXqz2o45XTsOR3WaJfbEx51yscGx4SFr0Gtl6DKSTXol-3tkqkMZ3JhP7-JXk7RHwj1c3PhDTwXcgc6c8gq4qOMSwaR_EWnZtn8vX5ICc&state=d4e6fd2949abda8f85810e36a4a3fc35#_=_
```

and again redirect to the first URL and back to the second URL and so on.

Here is a screen shot of the Facebook Client OAuth Settings

if someone like to see the controller I will provide the controller too.

[image]

Comment: How can the vote happen successfully, if the login via Facebook did not work in the first place? Sounds like you did not implement this properly to begin with. // If it automatically redirects “endlessly” between those two URLs, that must mean you are automatically redirecting to the login dialog when you don’t have a valid user - which is something you should not do to begin with. Facebook will notice when users try to break out of such a trap without success, and eventually ask people to report your app for this behavior. [...]

Comment: So you should offer them a button/link to click to _request_ login; or at least not send them back to the dialog when they already once returned from there - in that case, a proper check for errors and the possibility to try again is what should happen. // Problem itself is likely due to problems with 3rd-party cookies or the session; I’d start debugging in those regards.